# WPF Lock Window Size to Viewbox Size

Tags: wpf, window, stretch, viewbox, uniform

I have a window that contains a resizable viewbox with a uniform stretch.  The window frame however does not stretch uniformly.  So when someone resizes the form gaps of whitespace open up along one or another edge of the form.  Looks bad.  Any way to force the window to only expand uniformly?  (or another way to look at it, lock it to the viewbox boundaries)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `ResizeMode` option in `MainWindow` property. Set as `NoResize`
window size will not change at run.

You can set this as `CanMinimize`, `CanResize` & `CanResizeWithGrip`.

Comment: This isn't quite what I was looking for, but +1